# How to fix discrepancies between github repository and github desktop?

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I am a bit new to git hub so my terminology might not be perfect.
I am developing collaboratively with someone else using gitub and a private repository.

For a while the other contributor's changes were not showing up on my github desktop client even though they were on github. He also could not see my changes on is github desktop client.

we cloned the repositories again and now the new changes are showing up

However the changes that were made by the collaborator during that that still do not show in the github desktop client, neither on hs computer nor on mine.

We are both making changes to the "master" branch and there are no other branches. How can I resolve these differences I am afraid that this indicative of some greater problem and might lead to lost code in the future

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to GitHub you can simply use the sync button on the GitHub for Desktop application to keep your local repository uptodate.

See the official documentation:
https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/

Comment: The sync button is not causing all of the changes to show for all contributors. The log that appears on the desktop app is different (fewer changes than) the log on github itself.